# NoMethodError in Users#edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a rails app whereby you can edit your account information. When I click the `edit my information` button i receive the following error when I click the link.

> NoMethodError in Users#edit - undefined method `name' for
>   nil:NilClass

Which is pointing to the following line of my users/_form.html.erb

```
<% else %> <td><%= @user.admin_level.name %>
```

My full trace follows: [Pastie](http://pastie.org/3503593)

It appears something is wrong with `user.admin_level.name` What I cannot seem to understand is why this error is occurring also the attribute name exist in the admin_level entity.

My users_controller has the following def edit:

```
 # GET /users/:id/edit
  def edit
    if @user
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # edit.html.erb
      end
    else
    redirect_to routing_error_path
    end
  end
```

Its seems that I am missing something, do I need to define the name in my users_controller?

Comment: The admin_level is nil so you can't call a method on it. To avoid this exception from blowing up, try this code instead <%= @user.admin_level.try(:name) %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply means that `<%= @user.admin_level %>` is `nil`. This is maybe because the user has no admin_level assigned. Therefore, calling `.name` on nil which results in a noMethodError.

Correct would be `<%= @user.admin_level.name if @user.admin_level %>`, or maybe `<%= @user.admin_level.try(:name) %>` (which both only display something if `admin_level` is not nil)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the exception it seems that @user.admin_level is nil.

Can you check if this is really set (use a debug-statement) and post how @user is set?